# Is it possible for a Transit Gateway to propagate/advertise its known routes to the VPC route tables?

Tags: amazon-vpc

I have two VPCs

- VPC1: 10.1.0.0/16
- VPC2: 10.2.0.0/16

I have a Transit Gateway with attachments in both VPCs. I see that the Transit Gateway "learns" about the routes in each VPC, so that the TGW route table has the proper routes.

But the VPC route table has no route to the TGW, if I add that route manually to both VPC route tables then I will work (I'll have connectivity between instances in both VPCs):

- VPC1 route table : 10.2.0.0/16 -> tgw-xxxxx
- VPC2 route table : 10.1.0.0/16 -> tgw-xxxxx

This is fairly simple now that the TGW route table is minimal, but I'm concerned about how it will be when the TGW routes gets bigger.

Is there any way to configure the VPC to learn the routes advertised by the TGW?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like it's possible to propagate route **from** TGW **to** VPC.

Quoting from [How transit gateways work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/how-transit-gateways-work.html):

> Each attachment comes with routes that can be installed to one or more transit gateway route tables. When an attachment is propagated to a transit gateway route table, these routes are installed in the route table.
>
> For a VPC attachment, the CIDR blocks of the VPC are propagated to the transit gateway route table.

The [Example:Isolated VPCs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/transit-gateway-isolated-shared.html) seem to indicate that the VPC route tables must be modified manually. In this example the **route table in each VPC is greatly simplified** by the fact that they add a `0.0.0.0/0` route to the TGW to each VPC route table. That can be used your VPC do not need direct internet connectivity via Internet Gateway or NAT Gateway.